# Integration test Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using Zuul as an Api-Gateway. In this way I'm injecting various headers into the original request to the backend service.

Is there any way to integration-test this behavior?

I already came along [`SimpleHostRoutingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java) which seems to do the actual call to the backend service. But I don't get a mocking-foot into the door, since it constructs the `HttpClient` without injection.

I'm using Spock for testing, in this way there is no support for `@MockBean` right now.

Edit: Picture for better understanding.

I want to test the call to the origin server, because I don't have this one on build.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you mean unit testing? Integration testing would be to run a real http request. That is what we do https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul

Comment: In my view unit testing wouldn't have a spring context. But maybe it's in between unit testing and real integration testing. I want to run a real HTTP request, without having a service in the backend running. So I'm trying to put something into the black box and check it, when it tries to exits to the backend service. Otherwise I would have to have an external dependent service, which has to be present when I run my build test.

Comment: your title says integration testing. you can use something like https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was searching for!